# Finding Google analytics onclick event tracking code script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, event-tracking

I am auditing a site that uses GTM to fire events on PDF clicks. We have access to GTM and updated the tag to categorize these clicks correctly.

However, I am still seeing the old version of event tracking showing up in Analytics.

I am wondering if there is an `onClick` event being triggered to track PDF clicks. Is there a way to use the console to see what `onClick` events are being triggered and debug these events?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Google Analytics Debugger** add-on:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

> This extension loads the debug version of the Google Analytics
> Javascript for all sites you browse using Google Chrome.  It prints
> useful information to the Javascript console.  These messages include
> error messages and warnings which can tell you when your analytics
> tracking code is set up incorrectly.  In addition, it provides a
> detailed breakdown of each tracking beacon sent to Google Analytics.

[image]